# How to select element and surrounding elements from array, preferring return array with selected element in middle?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let `initial_array = (1..10).to_a`.

I need it to be dynamic on number selection, but for an example: I need to select the number `5`, as well as two elements on either side. Ideally, this would return: `[3,4,5,6,7]`.

I know I can use [each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) to return the desired array length, with surrounding numbers. However, to select the desired element, I'm currently using `initial_array.each_cons(5).find {|ary| ary.include?(5)}`.

This returns `[1,2,3,4,5]`, rather than the desired `[3,4,5,6,7]`.

Additionally, I would like the function to work on both ends of the spectrum, with the returned array always at length `5`, unless `initial_array.length < 5`, at which point `returned_array.length == intial_array.length`.

Thus, `initial_array.solution_method(1)` returns `[1,2,3,4,5]`,

`initial_array.solution_method(10)` returns `[6,7,8,9,10]`,

`[1,2,3,].solution_method(2)` returns `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a one liner but maybe easier to understand?

```
input = (1..10)

def select_range(array, num, range)
  index = array.index(num) # find the value
  return [] if !index # return if the array doesn't include it

  array[(index - range)..(index + range)] # return the range of elements
end

p select_range(input.to_a, 5, 2)
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: It's perfect for the middle of the array! However, if `num <= 2`, returns `[]` due to negative index on return array. 

If `num >= 9`, returns a shorter array, as `array[index + range]` doesn't exist.

Comment: What are the expectations for ranges outside of the array boundaries? does it truncate?  does it need to be exactly range length at the end?  There are edge cases here that you'll likely need to define before we can code more.

Comment: Tried to address in edits. 

`return_ary.length == init_ary.length if init_ary.length < 5`

Comment: `if init_ary.index(num) < 2`

  `return_ary.index(num)` 0 or 1, length still 5 (unless above), trailing numbers after

Comment: `elsif init_ary.index(num) > init_ary.length - 2`
  `return_ary.index(num)` 3 or 4, length still 5, more numbers before `num`

Answer (score 1):

```
def grab_part(arr, nbr, option=:avg)
  return nil unless (1..arr.size).include?(nbr)
  return nil if option!=:avg && !(nbr-1...arr.size).include?(option)
  first = (option==:avg) ? (arr.size-nbr)/2 : option-nbr+1
  arr[first,nbr]
end
```

`nbr` is the size of the array to be returned. `option==:avg` if the "middle" of `arr` is to be returned; else `option` is an index into `arr` identifying the last element of the array to be returned.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

grab_part(arr,5)   #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
grab_part(arr,5,9) #=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,5,4) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The following shows returned values for other values of the second parameter of `grab_part`.

```
(1..arr.size).map do |n|
  next if n==5
  puts "grab_part(arr,#{n}) \#=> #{ grab_part(arr,n) }" 
  puts "grab_part(arr,#{n},#{arr.size-1}) \#=> #{grab_part(arr,n,arr.size-1)}"
  puts "grab_part(arr,#{n},#{n-1}) \#=> #{grab_part(arr,n,n-1)}\n"
end
grab_part(arr,1)    #=> [5]
grab_part(arr,1,9)  #=> [10]
grab_part(arr,1,0)  #=> [1]
grab_part(arr,2)    #=> [5, 6]
grab_part(arr,2,9)  #=> [9, 10]
grab_part(arr,2,1)  #=> [1, 2]
grab_part(arr,3)    #=> [4, 5, 6]
grab_part(arr,3,9)  #=> [8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,3,2)  #=> [1, 2, 3]
grab_part(arr,4)    #=> [4, 5, 6, 7]
grab_part(arr,4,9)  #=> [7, 8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,4,3)  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
grab_part(arr,6)    #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
grab_part(arr,6,9)  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,6,5)  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
grab_part(arr,7)    #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
grab_part(arr,7,9)  #=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,7,6)  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
grab_part(arr,8)    #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
grab_part(arr,8,9)  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,8,7)  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
grab_part(arr,9)    #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
grab_part(arr,9,9)  #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,9,8)  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
grab_part(arr,10)   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
grab_part(arr,10,9) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

A few more.

```
grab_part(arr,5,6)  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
grab_part(arr,5,8)  #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
grab_part(arr,5,3)  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
  #=> nil 
grab_part(arr,5,10) #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Not totally clear on how option was supposed to address? I'm sure you have something, just not seeing the correlation. I'm getting `1 <= option >=4` truncating the returned array

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your task, you can use the `slice` method. Just fyi, `(1..10)` is a range object, not an array. To use the `slice` method, you need to change the range to an array first using `(1..10).to_a`

`slice` takes two inputs, starting index, and length. So you can do `(1..10).to_a.slice(2,5)` to get `[3,4,5,6,7]`

Comment: He doesn't know where the starting index is so there's more work to do here  to make this complete.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear in the initial post. Need the targeted number to be dynamic. This works great if I know the target number and where that number is in the array. However, becomes more difficult when trying to target the later numbers of the array. If `first input > 5`, truncates array

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current working solution. It's not as eloquent as I'd like, but it's effective for what I'm looking for.

```
def grab_neighbors(array, num, range)
  index = array.index(num)
  target_length = range * 2 + 1
  if index < range
    return array.slice(0, target_length)
  elsif index >= (array.length - range)
    return array.slice(-target_length, target_length)
  else
    return array[(index - range)..(index + range)]
  end
end
```